# how do you find the sum of the elements in an array of integers in javascript? (Below example not working))

Tags: javascript, arrays

This function returns `0` when I test it:

```
function sum(arr) {
  var i, sum = 1;

  for (i = 0; i < arr[i].length; i++)
    sum += arr[i];

  return sum;
}
```

Comment: `return arr.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);`

Comment: `arr[i].length` should be `arr.length`

Answer (score 3):

You can fix that by fixing the test in your `for` loop (test array length, not the first elements length):

```
function sum(arr) {
    var i, sum=0;
    for(i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
        sum += arr[i];
    return sum;
}
```

For a bit nicer method, you can use a reduce function:

```
function sum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(total, value) {
        return total + value;
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: You might want to start the `sum` variable at `0` rather than `1` in your first example.

Comment: I wasn't sure if `sum` starting at `1` was a requirement or not.  It doesn't seem to be, so I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

initialize `sum=0;` rather than `sum=1;` and check the length of array rather than its first element

```
function sum(arr)
{
    var sum=0;
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem.  He's comparing the first elements length.

Comment: @TbWill4321 agree, made the fix

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to get the length of an `undefined` value in the array.

Change `arr[i].length` to `arr.length` in order to get the length of the array.

You should also start the `sum` variable at `0` rather than `1`:

```
function sum(arr) {
  var i, sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try foreach:

```
function sum(arr) {
    var sum = 0;
    arr.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
        sum += value;
    }); 
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You are actually overwriting the function when you do `sum = 0` so it will only work once. Put the `var` back in there like the OP had.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Array.protottype.slice()`, `while` loop, `Array.prototype.shift()`

```
var n = arr.slice(), sum = 0; while (n.length) sum += n.shift();
```

```js
var arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
, n = arr.slice()
, sum = 0; while (n.length) sum += n.shift(); 
console.log(sum)
```